# gets text not url, is it rich text, can I get the link from edge browser?

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I copy a url from the Edge browser and paste it into here I get
a url e.g.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2uyzAqefyE&t=225s
```

When I paste it into a QTextEdit I get underlined text that looks like a clickable link, but it doesn't go anywhere if I click it.

```
<u>PyQt5 Tutorial - Buttons and Events (Signals) - YouTube</u>
```

If I use QTextEdit.toHtml(), I do get the url burried as the href in an < a > tag (picture below)

Is there a way to get the url into the box?

this is definitely related to [improved-copy-and-paste-of-urls-in-microsoft-edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/improved-copy-and-paste-of-urls-in-microsoft-edge-d3bd3956-603a-0033-1fbc-9588a30645b4)

[image: Picture of pasted text from Edge 'improved paste']

if I paste from pyperclip I get the url.

code produces:

```
Qedit url python - QTextEdit gets text not url, is it rich text, can I get the link? - Stack Overflow
Clipboard text https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562902/qtextedit-gets-text-not-url-is-it-rich-text-can-i-get-the-link
```

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'spreadsheet_updator.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.
import pyperclip
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(898, 216)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnGo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnGo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 100, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btnGo.setFont(font)
        self.btnGo.setObjectName("btnGo")
        self.txtFile = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txtFile.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 811, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.txtFile.setFont(font)
        self.txtFile.setObjectName("txtFile")
        self.lblTitle = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblTitle.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 211, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.lblTitle.setFont(font)
        self.lblTitle.setObjectName("lblTitle")
        self.prgProgress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.prgProgress.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 140, 118, 23))
        self.prgProgress.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.prgProgress.setObjectName("prgProgress")
        self.lblStatus = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblStatus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 100, 481, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lblStatus.setFont(font)
        self.lblStatus.setObjectName("lblStatus")
        self.btnPaste = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnPaste.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 51, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.btnPaste.setFont(font)
        self.btnPaste.setObjectName("btnPaste")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 898, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.btnGo.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnGo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GO"))
        self.txtFile.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste url or id"))
        self.txtFile.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "URL or ID"))
        self.lblTitle.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Spreadsheet Updater"))
        self.lblStatus.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Status:"))
        self.btnPaste.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste"))

    def clicked(self):
        # self.btnGo.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        url = self.txtFile.toPlainText()
        url2 = pyperclip.paste()
        print('Qedit url ' + url)
        print('Clipboard text ' + url2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, you point to: *When I paste it into a QTextEdit I get underlined text that looks like a clickable link, but it doesn't go anywhere if I click it.*, so I presume that it behaves like any editor when clicked: open the url in any service, for example open a browser.

Comment: my problem is I want the url, not the text. the process should be user pastes a link, I get the link. Whats happening is I'm not getting the link, I'm getting some title of where the link goes.

Comment: @KarlS how are you copying the url?

Comment: @KarlS Could you put the code with which you get that "text"? please provide a [mre]

Comment: Got it, code posted. I'm copying straight from the address bar in the browser (I'm using edge)

Comment: @KarlS If I copy the link in QTextEdit and press the "GO" button and I get in the console: `Qedit url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2uyzAqefyE&t=225s`
`Clipboard text https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2uyzAqefyE&t=225s`, please use `@username`

Comment: @KarlS Why did you delete your comment? You should add your post that in google-chrome works to have more information about the cause of the error.

Comment: ok, this seems to be an Edge only problem, I'd still like to get the url regardless of the user's Edge setting. ctrl-shift-V should paste the url for sure.

Comment: @KarlS 1. What do you get when you change `toPlainText` to `toHtml`? 2. Could you show a screenshot of the QTextEdit after pasting the url?

Comment: y, url is in the a tag, I should be able to parse it out, good call

Comment: @KarlS see my answer

Comment: @KarlS for future reference: 1. QTextEdit is for *rich text*, if you need a text field to paste urls, use QLineEdit (which should also probably solve the problem, since the plain text content of the clipboard is the URL); 2. a [mre] should be **both** minimal and reproducible: your code contains a lot of elements (including comments) that are absolutely unnecessary for your question, and could have been provided with less than half of the lines; 3. as the warning says, pyuic generated files should ***never*** be edited; 4. you should use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know about this "feature" (which I'd label as ***horrifying***, not to mention the security concerns it presents), but considering that you seem to need the input field to type/paste a *valid* URL you have three options besides the solution from eyllanesc:

1. Use a QLineEdit: since the text field is used to paste URLs, using a QTextEdit (which is intended to display *rich text*) is pointless; considering that the plain text of the clipboard properly returns the url, and QLineEdit uses the plain text contents for the clipboard, that should solve the problem at its source;
2. If you still want a more advanced editor (for instance, you want to add multiple urls), you can set the [`acceptRichText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#acceptRichText-prop) property (`self.txtFile.setAcceptRichText(False)`) or uncheck it in Designer, so that it will always use the *plain text* of the clipboard;
3. A better alternative for the case above, is to use [QPlainTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html) which doesn't accept rich text by default but still supports multiple lines;

Comment: self.txtFile.setAcceptRichText(False) is the best fix for me

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen in the printout, the link is in the html href, so it is not seen in the plaintText. For this case you can use BeautifulSoup:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

```py
html = self.txtFile.toHtml()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
el = soup.find(href=True)
if el is not None:
    url = el["href"]
    print(url)
```

Comment: Considering the possible purpose of the text field, and the incredibly (and I'd say disgusting) annoying "feature", wouldn't it be better to use `self.txtFile.setAcceptRichText(False)`?

Comment: @musicamante Maybe it is an alternative for the possible background purpose (since it is only speculation) but not for the current question which is how to get the url.

Comment: looks like it would work

Comment: @eyllanesc You're right, this question is probably in the middle between answering "the specific problem" and "the broader one".